# looping through dynamically generated textareas

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to loop through and retrieve the values of a bunch of dynamically generated textareas on my vb.net webpage.

The user can add textareas via jQuery, and when they click the save button, I need to gather up all of the data they entered into these textareas.

So I wrote a little loop(below), but it always throws a null error even if all the text areas are filled.

Thanks for any helps or suggestions!

Here's my code:

```
    Dim divContainter As HtmlGenericControl = CType(Page.FindControl("divContainter"), HtmlGenericControl)

    For Each control As TextBox In divContainter.Controls.Cast(Of TextBox)()
        If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
            'do stuff
            Response.Write(control.Text)
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: I think....controls are generated on client side, so those controls wont be there at server side in postback event.  You will get those values.  However when page postback, then values received by page via FORM fields.

Comment: @Nps I'm not sure I follow you...

Comment: dynamically created control at client side doesn't get posted back to server.  However it just post the values which can be accessed via Request.Form["<controlname>"].  Based on this information, you can create control in postback event to show controls & values when response returns to client.

Comment: so I would do something like Request.Form["divContainter"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to retrieve textboxes generated by jQuery from server side. For the server controls do not exist if they were created on the client side. What you can do is use JSON to capture the textboxes and post back the page.

Here is a sample code that I used in a similar situation:

```
    function SubmitResources() {
        var activeDiscipline = $('#<%=tcDisciplines.ClientID%> .ajax__tab_active').first().attr('id').replace(/\D/g, "");
        var ctrID = $('#<%=hfCTRID.ClientID%>').val();
        var ctrDescription = CKEDITOR.instances['<%=tbEditDescription.ClientID%>'].getData().replace(/[|]/g, "");

//before this part I retrieved the data from needed controls

        var json = activeDiscipline + "|" + ctrID + "|" + ctrDescription + "|"; // here I add initial data into the JSON variable

        $('#<%=tblEdit.ClientID%> .trRes').each(function () {
            var resID = $(this).find("#resource").attr("name");
            var resH = $(this).find(".resH").val();
            var resC = $(this).find(".resC").val();
            json += resID + ';' + resH + ';' + resC + '|'
        }); //this loop goes through generated text boxes and appends the data with separators

        var options = { //set JSON options
            type: "POST",
            url: window.location + "&Update=Resource", //append QueryString
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        };

        $.ajax(options); //Postback
    }
```

Set the function to the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEditSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="Edit" OnClientClick="SubmitResources()" />
```

Go to your .aspx.vb and handle Init event

```
            If Not IsNothing(Request.QueryString("Update")) Then
                'If the query string was passed from jQuery, capture the JSON value and submit
                Dim sr As New StreamReader(Request.InputStream)
                Dim line As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
                Dim resources As String() = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1).Split("|")

                'Do your magic here. Now 'line' looks like this: 0;10;100|1;20;200|2;200;2000. 'resources' is an array with values as so: 0;10;100 Loop through the array and get the needed data.
            End If
```